# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while accessing the webservice

Tags: web-services, axis

I'm new to Axis. Axis(1.4) has been added to my webapp that runs on JBoss.

While invoking any service I'm getting the error:

```
[STDERR] AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue as well using Axis, Eclipse and Amazon Web Services with Beanstalk.   Any web service method that referenced my data model class which contained a static initialize method would generate this exception.  (WebServiceMethod -> WebServiceClass-> ClassWithStaticInitializer -> StaticInitialzerThatFails)

Even catching and trying to deal with this gracefully would not work.  The fix was copying the mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar driver into WebContent\WEB-INF\lib

```
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();            
        } 
        catch (Exception err)
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Some folks have reported this kind of problem when multiple copies of the Ajax files are on the classpath. For exmample, your applciation server supplies the Ajax classes in its runtime and you also have them packaged in your WAR or EAR.

Comment: Jboss's lib folder doesn't contain any axis jars